# Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray ..The Error i am recieving continuously

Tags: java, php, android, json, parsing

HERE is php file result

> Array[{"username":"abc","userpassword":"abc","id":"123456789"}]

Here is Code of getting response through HTTPConnection ..

```
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            // create connection
            URL wsURL=new URL(params[0]);
            conn=(HttpURLConnection) wsURL.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);;
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);

            // get data
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

            // converting InputStream into String

            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                in.close();

                String jsonResult=sb.toString();
                return jsonResult;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());
            }
```

And The Code Through Which i am parsing string result into jsonArray and JsonObject

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String username = json.getString("username");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            error2 = e.getMessage().toString();
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

There is an error that "Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Comment: See where the word 'Array' is prepended to your JSON string? It shouldn't be.

Comment: sorry i did not get what you said .... ! can u explain me

Comment: Your PHP code is printing out an array before the JSON. PHP expertly handles the array-to-string conversion by printing the literal string "Array". Fix your PHP.

Comment: can you post complete php response

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1064767/sammitch
Thanks for your Help... i got that ... this was stupid check point... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
  try {
            result  = result.replace("Array","");
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
            String username = json.getString("username");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            error2 = e.getMessage().toString();
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: `[{"example":"This text foolishly contains the word 'Array'."}]`

Comment: The response will be Array[{"example":"This text foolishly contains the word 'Array'."}]. because Array will always be appended before the JsonArray. And I am using replace and not replaceAll. So it will clear only the first occurrence.

Comment: yep i got that ... i review my php file and got this stupid check point ;) thanks for your help... !